# Popupmenu disturb for correct onMouseOut

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an INPUT element in my html and I work with `onMouseOut` event for this INPUT. All is fine except popupmenu (context-menu) when its popup in INPUT - **onMouseOut of INPUT** is raised (may be it right - positions in context menu is out of border than INPUT). How to **NO** raise INPUT-`element.onMouseOut`, if context menu pop ups on INPUT?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function onMouseOut(event) {
       var e = event.toElement || event.relatedTarget;
      if (e.parentNode == this || e == this) {
         return;
      }
    alert('MouseOut');
  }

  document.getElementById("first").addEventListener('mouseout', onMouseOut, true);
  \\ this string does not have any effect on my drupal6
  \\ how I can directly use this function to my INPUT below?
  }

  </script>


 <input type="text" id="first" size="12" readonly="readonly" value="01234567890" title="Click here" onMouseOver="this.select();">
```